# How to return HashMap object fields

Tags: java, object, hashmap

I currently have the following HashMap in a Holiday class.

**Holiday Class:**

```
HashMap <String, Location> holidays = new HashMap<String, Location>();
```

This creates an instance of the Location class, to allow more fields to be shown.

**Location class:**

```
public class Location {
private String locationName;
private String locationDesc;
private double price;
private int quantity;

public Location(String locationName, String locationDesc, double price) {
    this.locationName = locationName;
    this.locationDesc = locationDesc;
    this.price = price; 
    quantity = 0;
}

public String toString() {
    return (locationName + " | " + "£" + price);
}
public double getPrice() { return price; }
public String getLocationName() { return locationName; }
public String getLocationDesc() { return locationDesc; }
public int getQuantity() { return quantity; }
}
```

In my GUI class I just use the .get HashMap method, this will return the toString.
e.g

**GUI class**

```
private Holiday holiday;
...
return holiday.holidays.get(--HashMap key here--);
```

this will return the toString, which is locationName and price.

However. I'm wanting to also print out the HashMap elsewhere, but with returning different fields. such as returning the Description and quantity as well as locationName and price. How would i go about doing this? Or how do i return the individual fields from the Location class which is an instance of in the HashMap.

**MANAGED TO DO THIS. But need help with the following below**

---

Second EDIT:

I have a set quantity method in my Location class, to set the amount of bookings for each holiday. However when using;

```
for (Location location : holiday.holidays.values()) {
location.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(textFieldQuantity.getText()));
}
```

This changes all of the holidays to the same quantity when setting each location with a different quantity. How do i fix this?

Comment: `Holiday.holidays.get` returns a `Location` object, not a string. And you can get anything inside it using the `getPrice()`, `getlocationName()` and other getter methods.

Comment: Why don't you iterate over the `HashMap` entries and build a `String` with all the fields you want from each `Location` object?

Comment: Read the stack trace of the exception. And read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Just altered the code so it tries to add it into the list instead of printing it. I get the NullPointerException on the .addElement line. How do i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `holidays.get(key)` should be an object of type `Location`. If you print the object directly, like in `System.out.println(holidays.get(key))` it will print the result of `toString()` as you say. But since you already have the object and access to its fields, you can print exactly what you want.

Something like this should work:

```
Location location = holidays.get(key);
System.out.println(location.getlocationDesc() + " | " + location.getQuantity());
```

Regarding your second question:

If you just need to print all values stored in your map, I think it would be cleaner and faster to iterate directly on the map values:

```
for (Location location : holiday.holidays.values()) {
    System.out.println(location.getlocationDesc() + " | " + location.getQuantity());
}
```

Third question:

Note that your code does not set the quantity for only one location. It goes through all locations setting each quantity to the same value, defined by `textFieldQuantity.getText()`.

If you want to modify a specific location, you need to retrieve it from the map using `get()`:

```
Location location = holiday.holidays.get(key);
location.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(textFieldQuantity.getText()));
```

Comment: This works - i've added an edit at the bottom of the post, by trying to iterate through it and add them to the JList. How do i fix that issue?

Comment: I updated the answer to address your second question.

Comment: Having an issue with using the setQuantity method within Location. When i set a quantity for one holiday within the list, it changes this for all of them. How do i fix this? Seems to be an issue with this for loop for doing it- – Added this as second edit on original question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something like:

```
private Location location = holiday.holidays.get(--HashMap key here--);

// Create a string with the variables
```

And then return the string.

Answer (score 0):

> this will return the toString, which is locationName and price

No. It will return an instance of Location. So all you have to do is

```
Location location = holiday.holidays.get("some key");
double price = location.getPrice();
String locationName = location.getLocationName();
```

Note that

- you shouldn't use public fields. So it should be instead `location.getHolidays().get("some key")`. Or even better, to encapsulate the Map and respect the "don't talk to strangers" rule, `location.getHoliday("some key")`.
- Your getter should be named `getLocationName()` and not `getlocationName()` to respect the JavaBean conventions. Or even better, since this method is part of a `Location` class, the location prefix is redundant, and you should thus simply name it `getName()` (and `getDescription()` for the description)